# ¿Cómo filtrar datos de un dataframe? Mejorar performance Python

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, condiciones, rendimiento

cómo están?

Mi consulta es la siguiente: tengo dos DataFrames (df1 y df2), en ambos tengo clientes con sus respectivos códigos. Necesito reducir el df1 de modo que me queden solo los clientes que aparecen en el df2.

Lo que hice es, primero, creo una lista con todos los clientes que tengo en el df2:

```
lista_clientes_df2 = list(df2["CLIENTE"].value_counts().index)
```

Luego, hago un for loop para que, vaya comprobando si cada cliente del df1 está en el df2, de lo contrario, que elimine dicha fila del df1:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if (df1["Cliente"][i] in lista_clientes_df2) == False:
        df1 = df1.drop([i], axis = 0)
```

El problema me surge ya que los df tienen aproximadamente 2 millones de filas cada uno, y el tiempo de procesamiento es muy extenso.

Una aclaración: el df1 tiene mas filas que el df2, ya que, además de tener mas clientes, los mismos aparecen repetidas veces (en el df1 las filas no son UN CLIENTE, sino que cada fila es UN PRODUCTO). No se si me explico.

¿Qué sugerencia me podrían dar para mejorar este código?

Muchas gracias desde ya!

Saludos

Comment: quizás lo que estas buscando es `.isin` y tu filtro seria algo como `df1[df1['cliente'].isin(df2["CLIENTE"])]`,  puede revisar esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/19960116/11539076

Answer (score 0):

la primera parte no se que tan necesaria sea con la función que te comentaré pero creo si es requerida, sin embargo para la segunda sección, basta usar la función .merge y emplear los parametros apropiados, segun me parece tu codigo quedaría así.

```
#Esa parte dices ya te funciona y es rápida
lista_clientes_df2 = list(df2["CLIENTE"].value_counts().index)
lista_clientes_df1 = list(df1["CLIENTE"].value_counts().index)
lista_nueva=lista_clientes_df1.merge(lista_clientes_df2, on='key', how='inner')
```

Creo con eso quedaría mucho mas rápido, y te quedarían en lista_nueva solo los que están en ambos df. Sin embargo, lo que deseas es botar de df1 a todos aquellos que no estén en ambos df, depende de como este estructurado, creo puedes modificar las lineas de arriba para hacerlo de forma directa, sin embargo hace tiempo no uso estas funciones y puedo cometer algún detalle, por lo que te recomendaría continuases investigando de la funcion .merge y por allí creo esta la solución.

Creo esto puede ser un buen inicio:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101